# hide/show group of checkboxes/lables with JS

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

So I'm trying to make a `Edit` option, where the user can click this button, and then all the `Checkboxes`, and a `cancel` and `save` button will appear. But my problem is that I don't know how to `unhide` all my checkboxes? I did try the `document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');` but it didn't work, so I might do it wrong?

In the loop when I used it I did `checkboxes[i].classList.remove('d-none');`

I'm trying to update my `editDashboardContent` function, to remove the class `d-none`, and also show my two buttons `cancel & save`. Can I give them all a group name, and then just say show all / hide all with that name?

```js
function editDashboardContent() {
    var el = document.getElementById("selectAll");

    //remove class
    el.classList.remove('invisible');
    el.classList.remove('d-none');

    //remove class
    el.classList.add('visible');
    el.classList.add('d-flex');

    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
        $(this).classList.remove('d-none');
    });
}

/**
 * Toggle checkbox status, all or none
 *
 */
function toggle(source) {
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i] != source)
            checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
    }
}
```

```css
.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 17px;
}

.switch input {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 13px;
    width: 13px;
    left: 2px;
    bottom: 2px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
    background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(13px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(13px);
    transform: translateX(13px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
    border-radius: 17px;
}

.slider.round:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="selectAll" class='align-bottom invisible d-none'>
    <label class='switch align-top mr-1'>
        <input type='checkbox' onclick='toggle(this);' id='exampleCheck1'>
        <span class='slider round'></span>
    </label>
    <p>Check all</p>
</div>

<label class='switch align-top d-none'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='exampleCheck1'>
    <span class='slider round'></span>
</label>
<label class='switch align-top d-none'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='exampleCheck1'>
    <span class='slider round'></span>
</label>
<label class='switch align-top d-none'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='exampleCheck1'>
    <span class='slider round'></span>
</label>
<label class='switch align-top d-none'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='exampleCheck1'>
    <span class='slider round'></span>
</label>
<label class='switch align-top d-none'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='exampleCheck1'>
    <span class='slider round'></span>
</label>
<label class='switch align-top d-none'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='exampleCheck1'>
    <span class='slider round'></span>
</label>

<button type="button" onclick="editDashboardContent();" class="float-left btn btn-primary rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-1 d-inline-block mr-2" enabled>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-pen" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="m13.498.795.149-.149a1.207 1.207 0 1 1 1.707 1.708l-.149.148a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-.059 2.059L4.854 14.854a.5.5 0 0 1-.233.131l-4 1a.5.5 0 0 1-.606-.606l1-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .131-.232l9.642-9.642a.5.5 0 0 0-.642.056L6.854 4.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708L9.44.854A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 11.5.796a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.998-.001zm-.644.766a.5.5 0 0 0-.707 0L1.95 11.756l-.764 3.057 3.057-.764L14.44 3.854a.5.5 0 0 0 0-.708l-1.585-1.585z"></path>
    </svg>
</button>

<button type="button" class="float-left btn btn-success rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-1 d-inline-block mr-2 d-none invisible" disabled>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-check-lg" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M13.485 1.431a1.473 1.473 0 0 1 2.104 2.062l-7.84 9.801a1.473 1.473 0 0 1-2.12.04L.431 8.138a1.473 1.473 0 0 1 2.084-2.083l4.111 4.112 6.82-8.69a.486.486 0 0 1 .04-.045z"/>
    </svg>
</button>
<button type="button" class="float-left btn btn-danger rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-1 d-inline-block mr-2 d-none invisible" disabled>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-x-lg" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M1.293 1.293a1 1 0 0 1 1.414 0L8 6.586l5.293-5.293a1 1 0 1 1 1.414 1.414L9.414 8l5.293 5.293a1 1 0 0 1-1.414 1.414L8 9.414l-5.293 5.293a1 1 0 0 1-1.414-1.414L6.586 8 1.293 2.707a1 1 0 0 1 0-1.414z"/>
    </svg>
</button>
```

Just to show what I'm making:

**Before I click edit:**

[image]

**After I click edit:**

[image]

Comment: So I just relished that `d-none` is on `lable` and NOT `checkbox` but the question is still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).classList.remove('d-none')` change like this on using jquery `$(this).parent(".switch").removeClass('d-none')`

```js
function editDashboardContent() {
    var el = document.getElementById("selectAll");

    //remove class
    el.classList.remove('invisible');
    el.classList.remove('d-none');

    //remove class
    el.classList.add('visible');
    el.classList.add('d-flex');

    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
        $(this).parent(".switch").removeClass('d-none');
    });
}

/**
 * Toggle checkbox status, all or none
 *
 */
function toggle(source) {
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i] != source)
            checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
    }
}
```

```css
.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 17px;
}

.switch input {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 13px;
    width: 13px;
    left: 2px;
    bottom: 2px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
    background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(13px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(13px);
    transform: translateX(13px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
    border-radius: 17px;
}

.slider.round:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="selectAll" class='align-bottom invisible d-none'>
    <label class='switch align-top mr-1'>
        <input type='checkbox' onclick='toggle(this);' id='exampleCheck1'>
        <span class='slider round'></span>
    </label>
    <p>Check all</p>
</div>

<label class='switch align-top d-none'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='exampleCheck1'>
    <span class='slider round'></span>
</label>
<label class='switch align-top d-none'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='exampleCheck1'>
    <span class='slider round'></span>
</label>
<label class='switch align-top d-none'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='exampleCheck1'>
    <span class='slider round'></span>
</label>
<label class='switch align-top d-none'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='exampleCheck1'>
    <span class='slider round'></span>
</label>
<label class='switch align-top d-none'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='exampleCheck1'>
    <span class='slider round'></span>
</label>
<label class='switch align-top d-none'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='exampleCheck1'>
    <span class='slider round'></span>
</label>

<button type="button" onclick="editDashboardContent();" class="float-left btn btn-primary rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-1 d-inline-block mr-2" enabled>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-pen" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="m13.498.795.149-.149a1.207 1.207 0 1 1 1.707 1.708l-.149.148a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-.059 2.059L4.854 14.854a.5.5 0 0 1-.233.131l-4 1a.5.5 0 0 1-.606-.606l1-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .131-.232l9.642-9.642a.5.5 0 0 0-.642.056L6.854 4.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708L9.44.854A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 11.5.796a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.998-.001zm-.644.766a.5.5 0 0 0-.707 0L1.95 11.756l-.764 3.057 3.057-.764L14.44 3.854a.5.5 0 0 0 0-.708l-1.585-1.585z"></path>
    </svg>
</button>

<button type="button" class="float-left btn btn-success rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-1 d-inline-block mr-2 d-none invisible" disabled>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-check-lg" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M13.485 1.431a1.473 1.473 0 0 1 2.104 2.062l-7.84 9.801a1.473 1.473 0 0 1-2.12.04L.431 8.138a1.473 1.473 0 0 1 2.084-2.083l4.111 4.112 6.82-8.69a.486.486 0 0 1 .04-.045z"/>
    </svg>
</button>
<button type="button" class="float-left btn btn-danger rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-1 d-inline-block mr-2 d-none invisible" disabled>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-x-lg" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M1.293 1.293a1 1 0 0 1 1.414 0L8 6.586l5.293-5.293a1 1 0 1 1 1.414 1.414L9.414 8l5.293 5.293a1 1 0 0 1-1.414 1.414L8 9.414l-5.293 5.293a1 1 0 0 1-1.414-1.414L6.586 8 1.293 2.707a1 1 0 0 1 0-1.414z"/>
    </svg>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#allCheckBoxes input[type=checkbox], #check_all,.action').hide();
    $('#edit').show();
    $('#edit').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('#check_all').show().attr('checked', false);
        $('#allCheckBoxes input[type=checkbox]').show();
        $('.action').show();
    });
    $('#toggleAllCheckBoxes').click(function (e) {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('#allCheckBoxes input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', true);
        } else {
            $('#allCheckBoxes input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', false);
        }
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="edit">Edit</button>
<div id="check_all"><lable><input id="toggleAllCheckBoxes" type="checkbox">Check All</lable></div>
<div id="allCheckBoxes">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_one">One</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_two">Two</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_three">Three</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_four">Four</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_five">Five</label><br>
</div>
<div class="action">
    <button id="cancel">Cancel</button>
    <button id="Save">Save</button>
</div>
```